# Concept of generators in group theory

Tags: group-theory, mathematics

I am in the process of learning group theory, and I am a little confused about the concept of generators. As I understand it, groups have associated "generators" that can produce every element of the group through combinations of themselves. But, I am having trouble showing this. For example, consider the $T_d$ point group. According to [this webpage](http://gernot-katzers-spice-pages.com/character_tables/Td.html#:%7E:text=The%20Td%20point%20group%20is%20generated%20by%20two%20symmetry,a%20non%2Dcoplanar%20%CF%83d.) it has two generators: any two $S_4$ axes or any $S_4$ axis with any $C_3$ axis. How would one go about generating all elements of the $T_d$ group given these symmetry operations?

Comment: This is a math question, not a physics one. Did you consider posting on [math.se]?

Comment: Write an arbitrary element of the group you wish to generate and prove that products of the generators can make such an arbitrary element of the group. Or, partition the group into simpler sections whose elements can be more easily represented arbitrarily and show that products of generators generate those elements. Etc.

Comment: Your question conflates two types of group: Lie (infinite, continuous) ones in your first part; and Discrete (finite) ones in your example, where a [presentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group) is considered. I fear most physics texts, talking about generators, mean Lie algebra elements, which you stay away from exemplifying! They hardly ever consider presentations for discrete groups. In any case, you *must* declare which of the two you are asking about!